# How can I see what happened before?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I loaded up my save of CK2 and see a `Righteous Imprisonment` notification on top. I remember the guy that I can now imprison but I don't remember who he tried to kill or actually killed. 
I notice my `High Priority Messages` and `Low Priority Messages` are both 0. I can't see past events in there anymore.
On the bottom there is a small + icon button that shows the log but it is empty.
I don't see anything useful in log files in my documents but maybe I am looking in the wrong files.

**Is there a way to see some kind of journal or log of the events that happened in the game?

Some kind of event summary?

A "Previously on CK2..."?**

I just want to see what happened and who he killed. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Are there any files that contain this information? Is the logs folder in the my documents folder the only folder containing this kind of data?
Are there any mods that do this?

---

EDIT: I found a mod that does what I want but it requires the Charlemagne DLC. See answer below. If I get this DLC and that mod, I will be able to log my actions right? Any solution that does not require this DLC?

Comment: So, just to clarify, the piece of information you need is who was killed by this guy, right?

Comment: Well, yes. Let's say that's the reason why I asked the question but I would like to go broader and be able to see some kind of event log where I could find this information among others.

Answer (score 3):

The [Charlemagne DLC](http://store.steampowered.com/app/292982/) adds a chronicle to the game that keeps track of some events.
There is also a [mod](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=382202581) available that expands upon this.

In your `Documents\Paradox Interactive\Crusader Kings II\logs` folder there are some log files. I don't see anything interesting in there though (almost all are empty for me).