# Will I benefit from Charlemagne DLC If I don't play with any of those characters?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I am thinking about purchasing the [Charlemagne DlC](http://store.steampowered.com/app/292982/) for Crusader Kings 2.
However I am not very much interested in playing with Charlemagne (or his brother or whoever the dlc adds). I am more interested in the additional features.

**Will I be able to benefit from this DLC if I don't play as any of those characters?**

I'm mostly interested in the chronicles feature. [Linked to this question.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/220170/how-can-i-see-what-happened-before). New cultures, seasonal transitions and regency overhaul sound interesting too along with the earlier start date. I assume I can benefit from these even if I don't follow the Charlemagne story.
Will I get Charlemagne related events if I play with someone else entirely?

Another way to word my question is **Are these benefits limited to the Charlemagne story or separate?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few events added to certain historical characters in the earlier start added in Charlemagne. The king of Sweden (Svithjod), for example has a few events surrounding him and his son (who becomes [Ragnar Lothbrok](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragnar_Lodbrok).

There are also many more events which aren't character specific but, if events are what you're looking for, take a look at the [Way of Life DLC](http://store.steampowered.com/app/329010/).

None of the other features require you to be playing Charlemagne, or even as a specific character. Viceroyalties, custom kingdoms/empires, the chronical and the Zunist religon are available to anyone who meets the requirements. As with all starts, the 769 start allows you to play as any character (but, with records from the period being rare and difficult to separate from legends, some characters are ahistorical).

Comment: Could you expand upon "with records from the period being haphazard"? I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that. Ragnar Lodbrok sounds interesting! I believe I need the Old Gods for that right? Thanks for your fast answer (other answers are still welcome).

Comment: @miva2 769 was in the middle of the Dark Ages so there's not much information on the period (and it's hard to separate some of it from legends). Paradox try to be as accurate as possibly but sometimes it's impossible to find any information about minor nobles or chiefs of tribes. Some of the characters, especially in pagan lands, are randomly generated.

Comment: Ah yea, thanks, I'm fine with that! :) I'm going to get both DLCs. Bought this in a humble bundle and end up spending way more on DLC. Their marketing strategy seems to be working on me.

Comment: In general, there is almost always something in Paradox DLCs that changes the game mechanics themselves, rather than just the available time period/characters.